# Copy a list element of key values in dictionary through python language

Tags: python

I have dictionary which have multiple key and those multiple key have multiple list so i want to copy specific value for a specific key

```
dict1={ '1' : [1,2,3] , '2' : [4,5,6] , '3' :[7,8,9]}
```

output:

```
if key  == 1 then print 3
if key  == 2 then print 6
if key  == 3 then print 9
```

Comment: If you want to get last element for key you can do: dict[key][-1]

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to only keep the last value of each list.

```
>>> dict1={ '1' : [1,2,3] , '2' : [4,5,6] , '3' :[7,8,9]}

>>> dict2 = {key:val[-1] for key,val in dict1.items()}
>>> print(dict2)
{'1': 3, '3': 9, '2': 6}
```

Comment: thanks for ans,
but if suppose i want to find only 2 in dict and print it 2nd element or any element
if 2 exists in dict then print '5' 
output : 5

Answer (score 0):

You can just specify which key and which value to access directly to your value. Here is an example:

```
dict1={ '1' : [1,2,3] , '2' : [4,5,6] , '3' :[7,8,9]}
key, valueIndex = '3', 0    # print the first element of the key '3' list
print ( dict1[key][valueIndex]   )
```